# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps creating virtual interface ens160:0, how to prevent?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, ifconfig

I am running a Pi-hole server on Ubuntu 18.04 that for some reason keeps making a virtual interface ens160:0

```
user@pihole2:/etc$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:6e:35:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.108/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

There is no reason I know of that a second IP is needed.

Netplan config below, and /etc/network/interfaces is blank.

```
  GNU nano 4.8                              00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
        ens160:
            addresses: ['192.168.1.108/24']
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.1.108]
                search: [park.local]
  version: 2
```

Also, Webmin shows that this is not activated on boot. I don't know where to look next.

Comment: It is possible you have a service that is assigning a VIP (Virtual IP address)? Something like keepalived, heartbeat..

Comment: This is possible. The server was assigned 192.168.1.111 when first installing pihole, which I have since changed to 192.168.1.108. Most likely, some service in pihole is stuck on the old address. I will re-run the install script and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

One of the Pihole services was still using the old IP address. Re-running the installer using pihole -r and specifying the 192.168.1.108 address resolved it.